# How to set derived class property from base class

Tags: c#, reflection

Let me begin by saying I am well aware of the dangers of doing this and understand 100% it's a "bad idea"... but...

How can I set a derived class property from the base class?

```
public class Foo
{
    public void SetSomeValue(int someParam)
    {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType()
                            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                            .Where(t => t.Name == "SomeValue")
                            .First();

        propertyInfo.SetValue(null, someParam); // <-- This shouldn't be null
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get hold of the property value in order to call SetValue?

Edit:

This was actually really easy. Doh.

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(this, someParam);
```

Comment: I think it is not possible the way you think it is.

Comment: If Foo needs access to SomeValue it should be declared on Foo, even if its as an abstract Property

Comment: How can the base class know about its derived classes?

Comment: @YairNevet Polymorphism and reflection?

Comment: I have the property information... I just need the instance... If I could cast this as the System.Type I already have, I could do it.#

Comment: Also, it is possible to just use _"GetProperty"_ to avoid the Linq. Then you can check for null in the case you're a subclass that doesn't contain SomeValue

Comment: depending on what you are trying to achieve, the more correct way is probably to hold some sort of dictionary in the parent, and in the child add stuff to that collection and expose them through properties...

Comment: @Ideae This code isn't my actual project... I lifted the code. The original dealt with multiple params. Fair comment...

Answer (score 0):

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(this, someParam);
```

Comment: Give at least some explanation about the code you're posting instead of answering with just one line

Comment: I did in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:**

```
var bar = new Bar {SomeValue = 10};
bar.SetSomeValue(20);
Console.WriteLine(bar.SomeValue); // Should be 20
```

**Declaration:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public void SetSomeValue(int someParam)
    {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).First(t => t.Name == "SomeValue");

        propertyInfo.SetValue(this, someParam, null);
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fiddle around with interfaces. This way you are at least coupling to an interface instead of the actual derived classes.

```
public class Foo {
    public void SetSomeValue(int someParam) {
        if (this is ISomeValueHolder) {
            ((ISomeValueHolder)this).SomeValue = someParam;
        }
    }
}

public interface ISomeValueHolder {
    int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo, ISomeValueHolder {
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @downvoter, can you please leave a comment on why you downvoted? I might learn something.